# MVC 5 with Visual Studio 2013 (Connection Strings in Repository Code when Deploying to Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My application works perfectly in that I work locally then publish to Azure, Code First handles all the database updates etc

However, I have a method in a class that does a SQL Bulk Copy and to get it working I used a hardcoded connection string

Now I need a neat way to have it 'auto switch' for me. So that when I deploy it automatically uses the LIVE Azure connection string and not the local database

i.e. here is an extract from the line I need to replace with say a application variable

Whats the neatest approach one could recommend for doing this :

```
            using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(@"Data Source=WIN2008-VM;Initial Catalog=AscxxxCF;User Id=exxxer;Password=suxxnx;Integrated Security=True", SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default))
            {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used, this allowed me to detect within the URL if its running from localhost :

```
                string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                string sConnect = "";

                if (url.IndexOf("localhost") > -1)
                    sConnect = "Data Source=Wxxxx-VM;Initial Catalog=AscxxxxF;User Id=emxxxxr;Password=suxxxxc;Integrated Security=True";
                else
                    sConnect = "Server=tcp:zlxxxxxs.net,1433;Database=AscenxxxxDB;User ID=scoxxxxd;Password=Sxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=500;";
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using conditional compilation like

```
#if (DEBUG)
    // Local connection string.
#else
    // Azure connection string.
#endif
```

or [Web.config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx?Redirected=true)?